# tkinter Frame Layout with grid and pack

Tags: python, tkinter, layout

I have a layout with Frame and pack some widwets inside. This works so fare. But for the treeview widget it doesn't work and gives a strange error:

> Display Names in the Treeview doesn't work with pack tkinter.TclError:
> cannot use geometry manager pack inside . which already has slaves
> managed by grid

Need help from experienced tkinter user.

Here my layout:
[image]

here, if I try the same with a treeview instead of a label widget:
[image]

here is my program:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# Main App
win = tk.Tk()

win.title('Layout Test')
win.geometry('1200x720+300+300')
win.resizable(True, True)


# Frame Design

top_frame = tk.Frame(win, background="#FFF0C1", bd=1, relief="sunken")
left_frame = tk.Frame(win, background="#D2E2FB", bd=1, relief="sunken")
center_frame = tk.Frame(win, background="#CCE4CA", bd=1, relief="sunken")
right_frame = tk.Frame(win, background ='lightblue', bd=1, relief='sunken')
bottom_frame = tk.Frame(win, background="#F5C2C1", bd=1, relief="sunken")

top_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky="nsew", padx=2, pady=2)
left_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=2, pady=2)
center_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew", padx=2, pady=2)
right_frame.grid(row=1, column=2,  sticky="nsew", padx=2, pady=2)
bottom_frame.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky="nsew", padx=2, pady=2)

win.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=6)
win.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=40)
win.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)

win.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
win.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=2)
win.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=4)


# Display Names in the Treeview doesn't work with pack
# tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside .
# which already has slaves managed by grid

treeview = ttk.Treeview(win)
treeview.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1) 

treeview.insert('center_frame','0','item1', text = 'First item',tag='T' ) 
treeview.insert('center_frame','1','item2', text = 'Second item',tag='T' ) 
treeview.insert('center_frame','2','item3', text = 'Third item',tag='T' )
treeview.insert('center_frame','3','item4', text = 'Forth item',tag='T' )
treeview.insert('center_frame','end','item5', text = 'Five item',tag='T' )

treeview.insert('item1','end','item6', text = 'Sechster Text',tag='T' )



treeview.tag_configure('T', font=('Calibre', 15))

"""
# Test works well with pack
MyLabel = tk.Label(center_frame,text="Label inside Frame1")
MyLabel.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
"""



# Program here



# Status Bar at bottom_frame works well with pack
statustext = tk.StringVar()
statustext.set(' ... choose your avm_xml file') # will be changed from file dialoge
status = ttk.Label(bottom_frame, textvariable=statustext, borderwidth='25', relief=tk.SUNKEN, anchor=tk.W)
status.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X) #fill='both', expand=False, padx=8, pady=8

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Comment: You can read in my comment in the code, what works and what not. I think ist could help to understand my problem.

Comment: Please include the error message in your question, it helps figuring out what is the issue.

Comment: Understood! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`treeview` has `win` as master, so when you try to pack it you get an error since you used grid for the other widgets in `win`. This is because the layout managers `pack` and `grid` cannot be used simultaneously in the same master widget.

On the other hand, your test label's master is `center_frame`, so you can pack it inside. If you change your treeview's master to `center_frame`, you will be able to pack it like the label.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# Main App
win = tk.Tk()

win.title('Layout Test')
win.geometry('1200x720+300+300')
win.resizable(True, True)


# Frame Design

top_frame = tk.Frame(win, background="#FFF0C1", bd=1, relief="sunken")
left_frame = tk.Frame(win, background="#D2E2FB", bd=1, relief="sunken")
center_frame = tk.Frame(win, background="#CCE4CA", bd=1, relief="sunken")
right_frame = tk.Frame(win, background ='lightblue', bd=1, relief='sunken')
bottom_frame = tk.Frame(win, background="#F5C2C1", bd=1, relief="sunken")

top_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky="nsew", padx=2, pady=2)
left_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=2, pady=2)
center_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew", padx=2, pady=2)
right_frame.grid(row=1, column=2,  sticky="nsew", padx=2, pady=2)
bottom_frame.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky="nsew", padx=2, pady=2)

win.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=6)
win.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=40)
win.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)

win.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
win.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=2)
win.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=4)

treeview = ttk.Treeview(center_frame) # <-- changed master from win to center_frame
treeview.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)  # <-- pack works now


# Program here

# Status Bar at bottom_frame works well with pack
statustext = tk.StringVar()
statustext.set(' ... choose your avm_xml file') # will be changed from file dialoge
status = ttk.Label(bottom_frame, textvariable=statustext, borderwidth='25', relief=tk.SUNKEN, anchor=tk.W)
status.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X) #fill='both', expand=False, padx=8, pady=8

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: .grid() frame and inside a text label with .pack() works, as you can see in my pictures. But I can”t .pack() a treeview into the .grid() frame.  I don’t understand the difference.

Comment: As I said in my answer, you cannot use both grid and pack inside the same master widget (here `win`): you are using grid for the `..._frame`, so you cannot use pack for `treeview`. What you can do is to grid `treeview` or to change its master to `center_frame` and pack it inside `center_frame`.

Comment: Got it, sometimes I have tomatos on the eys. Thanks, now it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am concerned, if you change treeview.pack() to treeview.grid(sticky=W)etc it might work. You can't have both pack and grid in the same widget.

Comment: I can .pack() a Label in my .grid() frame, this works, but not with the treeview widget. This is strange, isn”t it? Why?

Comment: Yeah it also works for me, I've done similar coding with this, I think the person above answered this correctly.